# R: variable lengths differ (found for '...')

Tags: r

I am doing multinomial logistic regression:
Here is the important code:

```
ml$Category2 <- relevel(ml$Category, ref = "NON-CRIMINAL")
test <- multinom(Category2 ~ DayOfWeek +PdDistrict+liquor+district+MoonPhase,data = ml)
b<- predict(test, type="class")
```

The problem is when I tried to make classification table, after I run the code:

```
factcrime<- factor(b, levels=levels(ml$Category))
ctab<- xtabs(~ Category +factcrime, data=ml)
addmargins(ctab)
```

Then I received the error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~Category + factcrime, data =
>   ml) :    variable lengths differ (found for 'factcrime')

Comment: Sounds like there is missing data: your vector of predictions may be shorter than the original vector, hence warning

Comment: Try chaging your predict statement to `b <- predict(test, newdata=ml, type="class", na.action=na.pass)`, so that the predictions for the missing are returned (hopefuly)

Comment: Great stuff, youre welcome